# rails aborted! when running `rails new` and `rails s` giving load error for nokogiri and dlopen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, apple-silicon

I am on macOS and tried starting a new rails app with `rails new MyBlog -T --database:postgresql` and I am getting the following error dialog (the same happens for `rails s`:

```rb
LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.11.2-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri/extension.rb:25:in `rescue in <main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.11.2-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri/extension.rb:4:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.11.2-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri.rb:11:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.1.3/lib/action_text.rb:6:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.1.3/lib/action_text/engine.rb:8:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/Users/me/CodeProjects/MyBlog/config/application.rb:12:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require_relative'
/Users/me/CodeProjects/MyBlog/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `block in perform'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:52:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/me/CodeProjects/MyBlog/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/me/CodeProjects/MyBlog/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/me/CodeProjects/MyBlog/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
/Users/me/CodeProjects/MyBlog/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:2:in `load'
bin/rails:2:in `<main>'

Caused by:
LoadError: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.11.2-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri/2.6/nokogiri.bundle, 0x0009): could not use '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.11.2-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri/2.6/nokogiri.bundle' because it is not a compatible arch - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.11.2-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri/2.6/nokogiri.bundle
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.11.2-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri/extension.rb:6:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.11.2-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri.rb:11:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.1.3/lib/action_text.rb:6:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.1.3/lib/action_text/engine.rb:8:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/Users/me/CodeProjects/MyBlog/config/application.rb:12:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require_relative'
/Users/me/CodeProjects/MyBlog/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `block in perform'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:52:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/me/CodeProjects/MyBlog/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/me/CodeProjects/MyBlog/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/me/CodeProjects/MyBlog/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
/Users/me/CodeProjects/MyBlog/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:2:in `load'
bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
```

I tried `bundle update` and `bundle install`, without anything changing.

When I try `gem uninstall nokogiri` I get

```
gem uninstall nokogiri

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. nokogiri-1.11.2-arm64-darwin
 2. nokogiri-1.11.2-x86_64-darwin
 3. All versions
>
```

und with 3 I run into

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permission error probably means the gem has been installed by user root, doing something like `sudo gem install`, which means you have to use `sudo` to remove it too.

Now the nokogiri gem usually relies upon what is called native extensions, i.e. code that has to be compiled for a specific kind of platform.

Here we can see you have nokogiri installed for both x86_64-darwin and arm64-darwin.

Here `darwin` refers to your operating system (mac OS)

`x86_64` is the code named for the 64bit versions of the intel family of processor, something also called `amd64` because the first such processor was developed by AMD.

`arm64` is another computer architecture, based on ARM which is often use in mobile phones and tablets because of it's lower energy consumption.

`arm64-darwin` refers to the new Apple Silicon architecture.

Now `dlopen` is the C api to load a shared-library (.so), and it reports clearly:

```
 could not use '.../nokogiri-1.11.2-arm64-darwin/l...' because it is not a compatible arch
```

So you know it's not usable on your system. which means you can probably safely remove it.

Additionaly, you could try using `asdf`, `rbenv`, `rvm` or something similar to manage your ruby versions, which will also keep your gems (depending on how you configure it) in your User's folder so you don't need to worry about `sudo`.

Comment: Ok thank you this helps clarifying though I couldnt solve so far my answer. I uninstalled and now i get `sudo gem uninstall nokogiri
Gem 'nokogiri' is not installed` ok when I delete  my project folder and tryp build with rails new again I get same error. I actually have rbenv installed and `rbenv global 2.7.2` and `ruby -v
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-darwin20]` but in my gemfile I have ruby '2.6.3', where is this coming from and might this be causing the troubles?

Comment: Always use the rbenv one then, install the required version or change the version in your project.

Answer (score 3):

I was just having the same issue on my local environment (MAC OS Catalina 10.15.7, ruby 2.6.3p62, Rails 6.1.3) and I was able to resolve it by doing the following.

```
# Remove all versions of the nokogiri gem
sudo gem uninstall nokogiri
brew install libxml2
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries \
--with-xml2-include=$(brew --prefix libxml2)/include/libxml2
```

Then remove the nokogiri (1.11.2-arm64-darwin) dependency from your Gemfile.lock.

```
nokogiri (1.11.2-arm64-darwin)
  racc (~> 1.4)
```

The idea of installing libxml2 via brew and using it for the nokogiri gem I got it from here: https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#macos-error-use-of-undeclared-identifier-lzma_ok (solution 2)

Hope it helps! Happy rails coding!

---

**Update**
You may not need to uninstall nokogiri and install libxml2. By simply removing `nokogiri (1.11.2-arm64-darwin)` from your Gemfile.lock may solve the issue

Comment: this sadly changes nothing when I start a new project with `rails new ...` I still get the same errors